# Custom Source For Reading Parquet File in Cloud Dataflow

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, parquet, apache-beam, dataflow

I have a requirement to read parquet file in my dataflow written in java and upload on bigquery. 
As there is no out of the box functionality given yet I know I have to write a custom source with hadoopFileFormat but I am not able to find any documentation regarding the same. Can somebody help me with some code or documentation on how to write a custom source or any other approach available to read a parquet file in Cloud dataflow.

Answer (score 1):

The Apache Beam documentation for [Built-in I/O Transforms](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/io/built-in/) provides a list of the work in progress for I/O Transforms in Apache Beam. Actually that list includes reading Apache Parquet files in Java, which can be followed in the [BEAM-214 Jira](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-214).

So as of now, you are right, there is no out-of-the-box solution for working with Parquet files in Apache Beam / Cloud Dataflow. However, progress is being made in that field, so feel free to keep updated on the Jira I shared above.

Also, you should know that Stack Overflow is not the appropriate site to ask for code or external tutorials/documentation on how to do something, so it will be really unlikely that you get that type of information. As per the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic):

> 4. Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software
>      library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack
>      Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.
>      Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve
>      it.

Instead, I would suggest that you first try an implementation yourself and then come back here with specific questions that can be better answered by the community.